# Setting spring.profiles.active to value with variables in application.properties

Tags: spring

Is it possible to set `spring.profiles.active` in `application.properties` to a value containing other variables? Apparently, I cannot get this to work.

Here is what I want:

```
one=${APP_ONE:foo}
two=${APP_TWO:bar}
spring.profiles.active=${one},${two}
```

Here, also the environment variables `APP_ONE` and `APP_TWO` should be interpreted and end up in `spring.profiles.active`.

I then want to be able to refer to this in `applicationContext.xml` in a `<beans profile="one">` tag.

Sorry, if I'm not clear enough here but I do not know how to be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. However you cannot define the variable for **spring.profiles.active** in the same(or lower precedence) of the property source order in which spring checks. The order is mentioned [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config).

In your case, you have tried to interpolate the variables "within" the same property source. **You can do it for other properties** but not for spring.profiles.active, because it is probably picked up first to enable spring to decide what other profile specific properties needs to be checked.

If you change your application.properties to

```
spring.profiles.active=${APP_ONE:foo},${APP_TWO:bar}
```

and then set the APP_ONE,APP_TWO variable with a higher property source order (for example command line arguments). It should set the profiles as expected.

I did not understand the second part of your question, but if  you want to know what profiles are active, programmatically, you can simply autowire Environment and call the corresponding methods.

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
```

Environment has methods like

```
String[] getActiveProfiles()
String[] getDefaultProfiles() //and 
boolean acceptsProfiles(String... profiles)
```